# R Shiny fileInput multiple filetypes

Tags: r, shiny

I can't find anything online or in the official docs for this, but is it possible to allow the fileInput command accept multiple file types? Such as csv and excel?

I've tried something like this:

```
x <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    inFile <- input$file
    if (endsWith(inFile, '.xlsx')){
      y <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
      return(gradesTbl)
    } else if (endswith(inFile, '.csv')){
      y <- read_csv(inFile$datapath)
      return(y)
    }
  })
```

But I get this error.

```
Error:non-character object(s)
```

Is there another way to check if an fileInput is of csv or excel format and then perform an action dependent on which one? Or do I need to create two seprate fileInputs for each type of document?

Comment: I think you want `endsWith(inFile$name, '.xlsx')` to check the file name. `inFile` is as list, not a string.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much I had no idea. I tried to paste(inFile) to see what would output wondering if there was an issue like that, but still couldn't figure it out. I'll mark your solution as correct if you post it!